# Locking property get/set

Tags: c#, .net

Is the following code safe, multiple threads are accessing a property but not writing to a particular object. New objects are being created and assigned. Multiple threads call `CreateXmlDoc` and `ReadXmlDoc`

```
public class DataHolder
{
    public XmlDocument XmlDoc {get; set;}
}

public class AccessClass
{
    DataHolder dataHolderInstance;

    public AccessClass(DataHolder _dataHolder)
    {
        dataHolderInstance = _dataHolder;
    }

    private void CreateXmlDoc()
    {
        XmlDocument _xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
        dataHolderInstance.XmlDoc = _xmlDoc;
    }

    private void ReadXmlDoc()
    {
        XmlNodeList elemList = dataHolderInstance.XmlDoc.GetElementsByTagName("title");
    }

}
```

Comment: Where is the data holder instance initialised in the access class? Is it shared between the access classes?

Comment: Please rephrase. Do multiple threads call `CreateXmlDoc`? If so.. then no, it isn't thread safe.

Comment: @SimonWhitehead Yes multiple threads call `CreateXmlDoc`

Comment: I am not sure, if anyone can comment if this code is thread safe or not, without knowing more about what is the desired semantics for concurrent read and write operations..

Comment: i posted an answer to make it 'thread safe'. i suggest you use it and see what happens.

Answer (score 1):

From purely technical standpoint, the code as you have provided above, would not exhibit any thread safety issues (i.e. data corruption etc).. The question you have to ask yourself is, from functional standpoint, what "thread safe" behavior is desired.

Answer (score 0):

The xml document is not thread safe.
To make this code thread safe:

```
public class DataHolder
{
    object lockObj = new object();
    private XmlDocument _xmlDoc;
    public XmlDocument XmlDoc
    { 
      get{return GetXmlDoc();}
      set{SetXmlDoc(value);}
    }

    private XmlDocument GetXmlDoc()
    {
       lock(lockObj) return _xmlDoc;
    }

    private void SetXmlDoc(XmlDocument xmlDoc)
    {
       lock(lockObj) _xmlDoc = xmlDoc;
    }
}

public class AccessClass
{
    DataHolder dataHolderInstance;

    public AccessClass(DataHolder _dataHolder)
    {
        dataHolderInstance = _dataHolder;
    }

    private void CreateXmlDoc()
    {
        XmlDocument _xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
        dataHolderInstance.XmlDoc = _xmlDoc;
    }

    private void ReadXmlDoc()
    {
        XmlNodeList elemList = dataHolderInstance.XmlDoc.GetElementsByTagName("title");
    }
 }
```